# Handling exceptions from a Method in a dialog that can be model and modeless

Tags: exception, visual-c++, mfc, dialog

This is an extract of a method in `CDialog` class:

```
void CDialog1::Method()
{
    try
    {
        // Snip
    }
    catch (CException* e_)
    {
        const gsl::not_null<CException*> e{ e_ };
        e->ReportError();
        e->Delete();
    }
    catch (const _com_error& e)
    {
        AfxMessageBox(e.ErrorMessage(), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

There is no issue with this function *when it is ran from an instance of the **modal** dialog*.

---

But, in another part of my application I load the same dialog as a **hidden modeless** dialog. And I call the same function. Eg:

```
void CDialog2::SomeTask()
{
    if (m_pDialog1 != nullptr)
    {
        m_pDialog1->Method();
    }
}
```

In this second scenario there is an issue with `Method` when an error is encountered. `CDialog2` needs to handle the display of the errors from what I understand, because the hidden instance will appear if it shows a messagebox.

How do I get around this? Note that `CDialog1` has a `boolean` method `IsHiddenMode` so we know if we are running it as a model or not.

What is the easy way to change my methods to cater for both scenarios:

- When `CDialog1` calls the method in it's modal dialog.
- When `CDialog2` calls the method using the modeless member variable of `CDialog1`.

I tend to overcomplicate my explanations so I hope it makes sense.

Comment: It now occurs to me, if I am in hidden mode I should just re throw the exception. Then in dialog2 add try/catch there for displaying.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I adjusted the `Method` to detect if the dialog was in hidden mode and throw the exception, eg:

```
catch (const _com_error& e)
{
    if (IsHiddenMode())
    {
        throw;
    }
    else
    {
        AfxMessageBox(e.ErrorMessage(), MB_OK | MB_ICONERROR);
    }
}
```

That way, the calling dialog could catch and handle with a `try` / `catch` block.